# IE8 floats incorrectly showing margin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, css-float, margins

My page is at http://jerswebempire.com/ovrtur/index.php

The page displays nearly perfectly in all browsers except IE8. In IE8, floated divs have incorrect margins. For example, you'll see the search bar at the top is sitting underneath the nav. However, if you open the page in Chrome or Firefox or IE9, it's displaying in the correct spot.

What am I doing wrong?! I can't seem to find a fix.

Also, the box for Latest Video is in two columns in all browsers but IE8. It's similar to the above problem where there is a left margin added that shouldn't be there.

The page was built with Bootstrap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ie conditionals between your index

```
<html> </html>
```

add a class to for the 'ie 8 only' margins like the html boilerplate does.

Load a custom ie 8 only stylesheet and play with the margin problem there like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-only.css" /> <![endif]-->
```

Or load a class where you need it.

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8 lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
```

Apply the ie conditional class to whatever you need.

```
<div class="floatedDiv ie8"
```

CSS

```
.ie8 { margin:0px; }
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work. I even tried adding a huge top margin to see if it would respond. It didn't. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can't debug on ie8 but I searched and found that there is in fact a [negative margin bug on ie7/8](http://www.trickyclicks.com/web-coding/css/negative-margin-for-ie7-ie8.html).
They recommend using

```
zoom:1, position: relative
```

as a workaround.